# Dynamically output the expression within each loop in handlebar emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Suppose I have the following controller

```
App.SomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  container: Ember.A(['one','two','three']),
  attrOne: 'Attribute One',
  attrTwo: 'Attribute Two',
  attrThree: 'Attribute Three'
});
```

In my handlebars, I can loop each of the value in the container array, but how I can dynamically populate each attr within the each loop

```
{{#each data in container}}
  {{data}} // one, two, three
  {{???}} // {{attrOne}} {{attrTwo}} {{attrThree}} ??? How ???
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars cannot do computations, and `{{#each}}` can only loop over a single array at a time. Therefore, the elements in the array you are `each`ing over must contain all the data you want to output. You can thus take the approach of defining a computed property which the data you need, which we will call `loopData`. The problem is that the only connection between the keys in your array and the corresponding attribute string is the name of the property, where the prefix is the key. So:

```
// in controller
loopData: function() {
  return this.get('container') .        // take container and
    map(function(key) {                 // create array which for each key
      var attr = this.get('attr' +      // gets property name starting with 'attr'
        key.capitalize();               // and ending in the key
      return { key: key, attr: attr };  // and returns little object with key and attr
  });
}.property('container.@each')
```

This will create an array which looks like

```
[{ key: 'one', attr: 'Attribute One' }, ...]
```

which you can loop over in the template:

```
{{#each data in loopData}}
    {{data.key}} // one, two, three
    {{data.attribute}}
{{/each}}
```

However, this is too much work and probably not a good way to structure your data. You're better off defining the basic properties directly as

```
container: [
    { key: 'one', attr: 'Attribute One' },
    { key: 'two', attr: 'Attribute Two' },
    { key: 'three', attr: 'Attribute Three' },
]
```

and then you loop directly over `container` without having to create an intermediate data representation.